# Highlighting and Un-Highlight a table row on click from row to row

Tags: javascript, html

I've been at this problem for awhile with no luck.

Please note. No jquery =/

The JS code I have is as following

```
function highlight(){
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
 for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
  table.rows[i].onclick= function () {
   if(!this.hilite){
    this.origColor=this.style.backgroundColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor='#BCD4EC';
    this.hilite = true;
   }
   else{
    this.style.backgroundColor=this.origColor;
    this.hilite = false;
   }
    }
 }
}
```

The HTML is as following

```
<table id="dataTable">
  <tr onclick="highlight()"><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
  <tr onclick="highlight()"><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
  <tr onclick="highlight()"><td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Currently when I click it changes color, however when I click on the second row the first row still remains highlighted. Could you please assist me in accomplishing this task with no jquery?

Thank you.

Comment: @OneTrickPony that was a typo while I was typing on here. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a working example of the following on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osewq1rq/4/)

Javascript:

```
function toggleClass(el, className) {
    if (el.className.indexOf(className) >= 0) {
        el.className = el.className.replace(className,"");
    }
    else {
        el.className  += className;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="gridview">
   <tr onclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');"><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr onclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');"><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr onclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');"><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.gridview .selected, .gridview tbody .selected {
    background-color: #6ccbfb;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: why the down vote?  this works as needed with less code

Comment: Good solution. How to deselect the rest when a new one is selected?

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same problem recently and just solved it using pure JS
Here is my version of it
https://jsfiddle.net/armaandhir/Lgt1j68s/

```
function highlight_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById('display-table');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;

            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";

            msg = 'The ID of the company is: ';
            msg += rowSelected.cells[0].innerHTML;
            msg += '\nThe cell value is: ' + this.innerHTML;
            alert(msg);
        }
    }

} //end of function

window.onload = highlight_row;
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to un-highlight the other rows, because now you are just changing the clicked one.

```
function highlight(){
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
 for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
  table.rows[i].onclick= function () {
   if(!this.hilite){
    unhighlight();
    this.origColor=this.style.backgroundColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor='#BCD4EC';
    this.hilite = true;
   }
   else{
    this.style.backgroundColor=this.origColor;
    this.hilite = false;
   }
    }
 }
}

function unhighlight(){
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
 for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
   var row = table.rows[i];
   row.style.backgroundColor=this.origColor;
   row.hilite = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: There is a small issue with your code which I can not seem to figure out where the issue is. It takes two clicks now for the table row to highlight on page load. After the initial first two clicks the table functions normally. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I was out a bit. Try to initialize `hilite` for every row after page load.

Answer (score 1):

not able to unhighlight rows when deselected

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function highlight(){
  var hilite;  
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
 for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
  table.rows[i].onclick= function () {
   if(!this.hilite){
    unhighlight();
    this.origColor=this.style.backgroundColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor='#fdee9a';
    this.hilite = true;
   }
   else{
    this.style.backgroundColor=this.origColor;
    this.hilite = false;
   }
    }
 }
}

function unhighlight(){
  var hilite;
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
 for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
   var row = table.rows[i];
   row.style.backgroundColor=this.origColor;
   row.hilite = false;
 }
}

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This demo table row selection has the functionality:

- Selects a clicked row, and unselects any previously selected row
- If already selected row is clicked on, it is unselected

NOTE: This is based upon the answer posted by @Richard YS

HTML:

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr onclick="selectRow(this,'selected');">
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="selectRow(this,'selected');">
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="selectRow(this,'selected');">
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="selectRow(this,'selected');">
        <td>Shankra Pillai</td>
        <td>India</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Java Script:

```
    let prevIx
    let prevTr

    function selectRow(tr, className) {

        let ix = tr.rowIndex

        if (ix === prevIx) { // row already selected, so unselect
          tr.className = tr.className.replace(className,"")
          prevIx = null
          prevTr = null
        }
        else { // no selected rows

          if (prevTr) {
            // unselect previously selected row
            prevTr.className = prevTr.className.replace(className,"")
          }

          // select current row
          tr.className += className
          prevIx = ix
          prevTr = tr
        }
    }
```

CSS:

```
table .selected {
    background-color: #6ccbfb;
    color: #fff;
}
```